# Why is Parsing a String containing a floating point number to Decimal Allowed?

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

Why is :

```
string arr = "3.14";
decimal element = decimal.Parse(arr);
```

Allowed

But:

```
decimal element = 3.14;
```

Not allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `3.14` is treated as a `double` literal unless you specify otherwise. And there is no implicit conversion from `double` to `decimal`.

You can use `m` suffix to make it a decimal literal:

```
decimal element = 3.14m;
```

You can refer to [C# Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) *§2.4.4.2 Integer Literals* for more info about literal suffixes.

Note that in the first code you are not directly assigning a `string` to a `decimal`, `decimal.Parse` returns `decimal` so there is no conversion issue there.